# How to pause a Runnable until another of the same type completed a task?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I would like to create a program that illustrates marathon runners with checkpoints. 5 runners are created and take a random amount of time to reach the first checkpoint. The runners must stop at the checkpoint until all of the other runners reach the checkpoint. There are 2 checkpoints and the finish line.

Here is some basic code that I thought would be the best way to implement this:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    Runner[] runners = new Runner[5];

    //Create 5 Runners
    for (Runner runner : runners) {
        runner = new Runner(i++);
        runner.run();
    }

    //Wait for runners to arrive at 1st checkpoint
    for (Runner runner : runners) {
        runner.arrivedAt1stCheckpoint();
    }

    //Wait for runenrs to arrive at 2nd checkpoint
    for (Runner runner : runners) {
        runner.arrivedAt2ndCheckpoint();
    }

    //Wait for runners to finish race
    for (Runner runner : runners) {
        runner.finishedRace();
    }
}}

public class Runner implements Runnable {

    public final int runnerID;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public Runner(int i) {
        this.runnerID = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("Runner %d exists\n", runnerID);
    }

    public boolean arrivedAt1stCheckpoint() {
        sleepThread();
        System.out.printf("Runner %d arrived at 1st checkpoint\n", runnerID);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean arrivedAt2ndCheckpoint() {
        System.out.printf("Runner %d arrived at 2nd checkpoint\n", runnerID);
        sleepThread();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean finishedRace() {
        System.out.printf("Runner %d finished race\n", runnerID);
        sleepThread();
        return true;
    }

    private void sleepThread() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(randomGenerator.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Runner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }}
```

Obviously this is barely structure and I'm missing a bunch of stuff so I'm not asking to write the whole program for me.
My main trouble here is getting each instance of the Runner class to communicate with the other instances somehow and sleep the whole program until the all the Runners reach the checkpoints.
Any "pointers" will help, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: Never heard of it, I'll check it out

Comment: You might want to try a ForkJoinPool. Take a look at the invokeAll method.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider CyclicBarrier or CountDownLatch. Here is a quick snippet using CyclicBarrier.

Set the barrier to desired count you want, pass the barrier along to the threads you want to wait on barrier, something like this

```
int BarrierCount = 4;
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(BarrierCount);

for (int i = 0; i <= BarrierCount; i++) {
    (new AppThreadsForBarrier(barrier, "name"+i, ...)).start();
}
```

Now in the threads that need to wait on barrier, something as below can be done

```
class AppThreadsForBarrier extends Thread {

    // barrier along with other variables you need for your thread
    public AppThreadsForBarrier(CyclicBarrier barrier, String name, ....) {
    ..

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is calling await()");
            barrier.await();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has started running again");
            ..
```

There are some nuances with respect to where to use CyclicBarrier v/s CountdownLatch but this should give you the picture to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You want a means of being able to check when all of the runners have made it to a checkpoint. This could be done by having a number of boolean variables to keep track whether or not your Runner has made it to checkpoint1, checkpoint2, etc.

```
public class Runner implements Runnable {    
    private boolean atFirstCheckpoint = false;
    // ... More checkpoint booleans 
    // ... Rest of the class

    public boolean hasReachedFirstCheckpoint() {
        return atFirstCheckpoint;
    }
}
```

If we keep a collection of runners (Array, ArrayList, etc.) we can then create a method that checks if all of our runners have reached a checkpoint.

```
public boolean everyoneHasReachedFirstCheckpoint(Runner[] runners) {
    for (Runner r : runners) {
        if (!r.hasReachedFirstCheckpoint()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

We can then change our arrivedAt1stCheckpoint() to implement this check. The Runner object will sleep until all of the other runners in your array have also reached the checkpoint.

```
public boolean arrivedAt1stCheckpoint(Runner[] runners) {
    this.atFirstCheckPoint = true;
    System.out.printf("Runner %d arrived at 1st checkpoint\n", runnerID);
    while (!everyoneHasReachedFirstCheckpoint(runners)) {
        sleepThread();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Edit:** It's worth keeping in mind that during the execution of the while loop the entire runner thread will halt for X amount of time depending on your sleepThread() method. This means a runner will literally be asleep for X amount of time before it checks if everyone has made it to the checkpoint which could very well result in the other threads getting a head start.

**Edit:** To try and manage your runners (threads) you might find using the Executor interface and/ or Thread Pools useful.